# Funcional Equations:I'm confused

Tags: functional-equations

I need help with this:

"Find functions $f$, $g : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, knowing that $g$ is injective and such that:
$$f(g(x)+y) = g(f(x)+x), \mbox{ for all } x, y \in \mathbb{Z}.$$
Or :
$$f(g(x)+y) = g(f(y)+x), \mbox{ for all } x, y \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: I note that this is not quite a duplicate, as the variables are different.  It may be that the techniques of the cited answer apply as well.  Certainly $f(x)=g(x)=x$ is again a solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the first, note that the right side is independent of $y$, so $f(x)$ is constant.  Then we have $f(0)=g(f(0)+x)$  with the left side independent of $x$.  Then $g$ must be constant, but it must be injective.  No solution.